# reading messages from tracking device over gprs

Tags: c#, gps, tracker, nmea

i have a tracking device Meiligao VT310 which send me messeages over gprs. I successfully read messagess with this code but it's not the same as I expected.

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
   Client client = result.AsyncState as Client;
   NetworkStream networkStream = client.NetworkStream;
   int read = networkStream.EndRead(result);
   string data = this.Encoding.GetString(client.Buffer, 0, read);

   networkStream.BeginRead(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length, ReadCallback, client);
}
```

I expect output in NMEA format, but output is like this:

$$\0}E!@ 5/??U154108.000,V,4619.3051,N,01549.5325,E,0.00,0,040112,,*1B|0.0|244|0000|0008,0006|0125004600323C97|0E|0000099C??\r\n

Comment: Sooo what did you expect? looks like GPS coordinates

Comment: Messages contains the unknown characters like \0}E!@ 5/?? and *1B|0.0|244|0000|0008,0006|0125004600323C97|0E|0000099C??\r\n

Comment: OK but what did you expect to get?

Comment: something like this
$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62

Comment: If your getting invalid characters this sounds more of an encoding problem.  How is this device connected to the computer in question?

Comment: Device is connected with TCP communication

Comment: Delve into its SDK and documentation if any.

Comment: GPRS TCP/UDP Communication (Meiligao Protocol) to be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meiligao VT310 uses its own protocol known as `Meiligao GPRS Communication Protocol`.

GPRS (TCP/UDP) packet command format are the following:

From server to tracker:

```
<header><L><ID><command><parameter><checksum>\r\n
```

From tracker to server:

```
<header><L><ID><command><data><checksum>\r\n
```

It's not NMEA at all but it may uses *GPRS NMEA 0183 GPRMC* protocol within its *data* part.

**Resources of interest:**

- Meiligao GPRS Communication Protocol [PDF documentation](http://www.meitrack.net/images/protocols/meiligao-gprs-communication-protocol-gt30i-gt60-vt300-vt310-vt400-v2.00.pdf).
- GpsGate relevant [post](http://forum.gpsgate.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=11216) in its Forum.